# How to print 3 arrays in one table and each array should represent 1 column?

Tags: php, html, arrays, printing

I have 3 arrays

```
$array1 = [a,b,c,d];

$array2 = [word,word1,word2,word3];

$array3 = [3,4,6,7];
```

and

```
count($array1) == count($array2) == count($array3);
```

I want to print them in to a table of 3 columns.

Can someone tell me how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it can help you :

```
<?php
$array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$array2 = ['word', 'word1', 'word2', 'word3'];
$array3 = [3,4,6,7];
?>

<table border="1">
    <?php

    foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $array2[$key] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $array3[$key] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array1 = [a,b,c,d];

$array2 = [word,word1,word2,word3];

$array3 = [3,4,6,7];

$tableStr = "<table>";
foreach ($array1 as $key => $array1Value) {
   $tableStr .= "<tr><td>".$array1Value.'</td><td>'.$array2[$key].'<td></td>'.$array3[$key].'</td></tr>';
}
$tableStr .= "</table>";
echo $tableStr;
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to look at defining these as a multi-dimensional array

```
$array = [['a','word',3],['b','word1',4],['c','word2',6],['d','word3',7]];

echo '<table>';

foreach($array as $row)
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row[0] . '</td><td>' . $row[1] . '</td><td>' . $row[2] . '</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

something like that